# How to recreate a ruby and rails database when using structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a database from an existing app. At some time in the past I squashed the migrations, so I cannot use db:create followed by db:migrate. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing database, first type

```
rake db:purge
```

then

```
rake db:structure:load
```